# Set Unique ID for selected rows in a table to store in localStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

I have a window which has drop down list and an HTML table where the table rows are populated on the basis of selection made in drop down list. Once the table is populated user clicks on each row for selection and clicks "OK" button. The user can also select only two out of three rows depending on the requirement. Once the "OK" button is clicked I store the rows selected in the localStorage using the following code and also preform some actions as follows:

```
 $('.ok').bind('click', function() {
    if (somecondition) {
        //some process
    }
    $("#selectedTblDiv tr:selected").each(function(index,row) {
        fnMatch($(row).find(("td:first").html()));
        localStorage.setItem("test-" + index, $(row).find(("td:first").html()));
    });
    fnDialogClose();
});
```

Here I have stored the first element of each row in localStorage with unique ID. While I am retrieving the same on page refresh I do the following process:

```
function fnDisplay() {
    //some code to open dialog   
    for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
        //some code and process
        var $select = $("#list_button");
        for (var j = 0; j < localStorage.length; j++) {
            if (localStorage.getItem("test-" + j)){
                var t = localStorage.getItem("test-" + j);
                if (t == prevIDs) {
                    $("#list_button > option").each(function() {
                        if (this.text == prevIDs) {
                            $(this).remove();
                        }
                    });
                    $('<option>').text(prevIDs).attr("disabled", true).appendTo($select);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here basically fnDisplay() opens a window and on some process drop down list is populated. And from the list user selects and the details are populated in the HTML table.Onclcik of "OK" it performs some actions and also stores the user selection of table in localStorage.

Again when the user opens the window the items in the drop down are disabled which were previously selected from the table. But the items which were not selected from the drop down are still enabled for selection.

My problem is as follows:

Drop down list has

```
10023
10024
10025
```

User selects 10023 and 10024 so HTML table is populated as follows:

HTML table

```
vehID    Name    Place     Summary 
-----    ----    -----     -------
10023    car     blore    4-wheeler
10024    bike    pune     2 wheeler
```

Now user selects the rows 10023 and 10024 and clcik "OK". 
Now the window is closed and reopened so my drop down looks as followss

```
10023   //disabled
10024   //disabled
10025   //enabled
```

and my html table is empty.

Now user has a provision to select the non-selected values. ie 10025
Now 10025 is selected and HTML is populated and the same row selection and "OK" button is clicked. 
Now when the user reloads the window I want all the options in drop down to be disabled as all are selected. But as localStorage is based on row selection its overwriting the stored values when new value is selected. Though I have given unique ID to each row as

```
localStorage.setItem("test-"+index,somethin);
```

The value of index is set to 0 again when a new row is selected . So my drop down list looks like this

```
10023  //enabled
10024  //disabled
10025   //disabled
```

So here 10025 is overwriting on 10023. How do I resolve this issue by giving an unique ID to each?

Comment: Your first JS code block is broken (missing `)` after `'.ok'` and also a `});` at the end) and extremely messy. Please use http://jsbeautifier.org/ to make this easier to read

Comment: Yes all were typing mistakes. Sorry now changes are done.

Comment: Are you aware of the fact that the code you've posted is full of syntax errors? a working demo such as [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) will be helpful for those trying to help you.

Comment: I have edited. Its tough to give a fiddle demo. So only I have explained my whole problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you are saving each selected item separately, causing existing items to be overridden when you're adding a new item.

Instead you can store an array of items in `localStorage` . When you're adding a new item, you can retrieve the array and push the new item into it. Something along the following :

```
var items = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("items")) || [];
$("#selectedTblDiv tr:selected").each(function (index, row) {
  items.push($(row).find(("td:first").html()));
});
localStorage.setItem("items", JSON.stringify(items));
```